# Unable to get property 'contentWindow' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have an Ajax Editor in a Bootstrap Modal. The first time the modal opens it runs fine, the next time to toolbar is no longer there and it throws this error. Any ideas what might be happening?

Thanks

```
Unhandled exception at line 84, column 9 in http://localhost:53818/ScriptResource.axd?d=QnqJUlWX76vy-voPv0SOyeWuqjSyItje2m_RwWfpN9Dp9KL-kVEuy2eIP-IxAD4LMlqvG3esYD48cWHYJvzAF9a1YRm5XmxfCzWi0PaDVAfNV8mz4aOOLZVDVbMrKXACgpSJB28TI_zeX-HTr-9ysw2&t=ffffffffda74082d
```

Error is thrown in ScriptResource.axd  - this._doc = this.get_element().contentWindow.document;

```
 _initIframe: function(value) {
    if (!Sys.Extended.UI.HTMLEditor.isIE) {
        this._savedValue = value;
        this._absAndFixedParents = this._getAbsAndFixedParents();
    }
    var str = Sys.Extended.UI.HTMLEditor.Trim(this._prepareContent(value));
    this._doc = this.get_element().contentWindow.document;

    if (!Sys.Extended.UI.HTMLEditor.isIE) {
        this._doc.designMode = "on";
    }
```

This is the modal

```
 <div id="modalEventsEditor" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">


            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="EventsUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>


                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button class="close" aria-hidden="true" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Events</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">



                        <div role="form">



                            <fieldset>
                                <div id="eventDateDiv" class="form-group">
                                    <label id="eventDateLabel" for="inputEventDate">Date</label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="inputEventDate" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="The Date of the event" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="inputEventDate"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
                                </div>

                                <div id="eventTimeDiv" class="form-group">
                                    <label id="eventTimeLabel" for="inputEventTime">Time</label>
                                    <input id="inputEventTime" class="form-control" runat="server" type="text" placeholder="The Time of the event" />
                                </div>

                                <div id="eventAuthorDiv" class="form-group">
                                    <label id="eventAuthorLabel" for="inputEventAuthor">Author</label>
                                    <input id="inputEventAuthor" runat="server" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="The Author of this notice" />

                                </div>

                                <div id="eventTitleDiv" class="form-group">
                                    <label id="eventTitleLabel" for="inputEventTitle">Title</label>
                                    <input id="inputEventTitle" runat="server" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="The Title of this notice" />
                                </div>


                            </fieldset>


                        </div>

                        <div id="editorContainer">
                            <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" />
                        </div>


                    </div>


                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button id="modalEventsEditorButton" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the MS Ajax async editor control is, well, not asynchronous!! About as much good as the proverbial chocolate fireguard.

As the MS asp.net forum use TinyMCE I went down that path. It was a bit of headache to work with a Modal but figured it out in the end - if anyone wants the method leave a message and I will post the code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; kind of.  I had an editor in a tabcontainer and the first time I entered the tab the editor worked(loaded). I would go to a different tab and back again and it would fail (Unhandled exception at line 84, column 9 in).  For my solution I turned off autoPostBack on the tabContainer.

Back in the day you used to be programmer; now your a property jockey...it's all voodoo.